# What is AVX-512 and how to leverage it in Python code?

Tags: python, performance, intel, cpu-registers, avx512

I have somewhat of an idea of what AVX-512 is, but how do I write my Python programmes in order to make sure that they make use of it? For example, to make use of the L1 cache, I can use arrays of contiguously allocated in memory data that are to be used sequentially and fit within the L1 cache. I can also make my code more predictable to leverage branch prediction. How do I code in order to make use of AVX-512 assuming I own a CPU that supports it?

Comment: Use a version of NumPy built with AVX-512 support.  I think it's unlikely that pure Python range expressions or loops over lists will get auto-vectorized even with SSE2 or AVX2.  (Especially because Python variables are references, so it would need AVX2 or AVX-512 `vpgatherqq` to dereference multiple pointers at once. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpgatherdq:vpgatherqq).

Comment: CPython is a pure interpreter so the only machine code that runs is pre-compiled, so the only hope is calling libraries like NumPy.  PyPy is a JIT if I recall correctly, but very unlikely it will auto-vectorize.  Cython can turn Python into C that a C compiler could potentially optimize, with `clang -O3 -march=native` you could potentially get some AVX-512 auto-vectorization on a machine that supports it, except that it would presumably still be using data structures with pointers, not contiguous arrays of float or double.  (And Python integers are arbitrary-precision, not like int64_t)

Comment: If you're not sure about SIMD in general, check out some of the links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info .  AVX-512 builds on that, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/avx512/info for some detail about what it adds, but that will make a lot more sense if you already understand SIMD.

Comment: "I write my Python programmes in order to make sure that they make use of it"  You cannot be 100% sure unless you use C/C++ SIMD intrinsics, assembly code or some vectorized functions of Numpy that have been already vectorized manually (not much of them yet but the situation is improving significantly the last 3 years). Most Numpy functions are auto-vectorized though and we use a dynamic strategy to use AVX-512 when it is available on the machine (as long as the build machine supports building AVX-512 codes). The best thing is to rebuild Numpy locally to be sure.

Comment: The benefit of using AVX-512 in basic Numpy functions is generally small except for some computationally intensive functions like sorting or trigonometric functions for example. For operation like add/sub/mul, they are generally memory bound and the overhead of Numpy function generally prevent you to really benefit from AVX-512 in small arrays.

Comment: In practice, when you use a compiler through Cython or Numba (both able to generate an AVX-512 code), the strategy is to write loops operating on contiguous arrays. For reduction, you generally need to enable fast-math optimizations so to get a SIMD reduction (due to the associativity of the FP operation enforced by the IEEE-754 standard). All of this help compilers generating SIMD instructions but you always need to check the assembly code so to be sure, get some feedback and adapt the code to fix what prevent compilers from vectorizing the code (iterative process).